# window.focus() not working with firefox driver

Tags: javascript, firefox, webdriver, driver

Using the following code to bring the window to focus, it works fine on Internet Explorer but isn't working with Firefox. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus()");

Firefox version: 5.0.1
Webdriver version: 2.25
```

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695715/javascript-focus-in-firefox]

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will only obey requests to raise a window if a security option is set, and it's not set by default.

The specific Firefox setting is in the "Tools" -> "Options" . There's a "Content" tabthre is is an "Advanced" button that brings up another dialog, wherein one finds a checkbox to allow (or disallow) the raising and lowering of windows by page code.

Comment: I tried that earlier based on the solution provided earlier in the following link, but it is not helping... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085544/why-window-focus-not-working-in-mozilla-firefox                                            Following is my exact code                                          driver = new FirefoxDriver();     
augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus()");

Comment: Do I have to do anything else since it is not helping pls suggest